# Doctrine2 - How to return an object instead of an array

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a comment form, but I'm stuck with something.

I retrieve my data with `findBy(array('slug' => $slug))` .

I know that this method returns an array, not an object. 
When I want to add a comment, I have an error

```
"Type error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Entity\Comment::setTrick() must
 be an instance of AppBundle\Entity\Trick, array given, called in
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SnowTricks/src/AppBundle/Controller
 /AppController.php on line 71"
```

How can I create, or use a method that returns an object ?

Thanks for your replies and sorry for my English

Comment: Please show more of your AppController.php code. Especially around Line 71.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to retrieve single entity, you should use method [`::findOneBy`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions)

```
$entity = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:Trick')
    ->findOneBy(array('slug' => $slug))
;
```

Comment: It works very well, sorry for this, I should have checked the findOneBy method returns an object ...